# Can a subclass access parent class private members if both the classes are in the same package

Tags: java, inheritance

I am reading [a Java Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) , which says

> A subclass inherits all of the public and protected members of its
>   parent, no matter what package the subclass is in. If the subclass is
>   in the same package as its parent, it also inherits the
>   package-private members of the parent. You can use the inherited
>   members as is, replace them, hide them, or supplement them with new
>   members

It says a Subclass can access the Parent's class private members if they are in the same package. I have tried it , I am unable to access the Private member of the parent Class in Subclass

Comment: It says `package-private` not `private`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it states

> If the subclass is in the same package as its parent, it also inherits the **package-private** members of the parent

`package-private` (no modifier) is not the same thing as `private` (`private` modifier). See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html for the differences.

Answer (score 1):

There is a **difference** between `package-private` and `private` members. Private members **can't be accessed by anyone other than the class itself**. But Package private members are those members who are **`private`** to that particular package only and they can be accessed by any member **within that particular package**.

[image]